What's the reason for the scriptCode format for a P2WPKH? (BIP 143)
When signing a P2WPKH input, the P2WPKH locking script is converted to the pattern of a legacy P2PKH when creating the scriptCode.
From BIP 143:

For P2WPKH witness program, the scriptCode is 0x1976a914{20-byte-pubkey-hash}88ac.

What's the reason for this?
Why not just use the original P2WPKH as the scriptCode?

Maybe one of the authors of BIP143 will correct me, but I think this was done to simplify the implementation in Bitcoin Core.
If you look at the code for P2WPKH validation, you can see it actually builds and executes a P2PKH script. This is just one way you could implement P2WPKH validation, and indeed BIP141 doesn't say anything about executing a script, however this simple 5-line implementation is only possible if the scriptCode for P2WPKH is the corresponding P2PKH script.

I believe the design decision was just to treat P2WPKH as a "special short notation" for a specific single-key P2WSH. That resulted in both the current code, and the effect that the scriptCode equals this specific form. In retrospect, this was a bad decision, because it means P2WPKH spends can be malleated into equivalent P2WSH spends by third parties, which slightly reduces the feerate of the transaction even.

@PieterWuille How can it be malleated when the signature commits to the outpoint(s)?

I misremembered; it's a somewhat different setting. The issue is with hardware signing devices: a malicious software wallet could create a P2WSH signature, present it as a P2WPKH spend to the signer, which would present a higher fee to the user.
